# Question about the TypeIII region in Green's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I'm trying to understand the proof of Green's Theorem. Every proof I see so far goes like the following: we consider Type I region then Type II region (described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) and then the theorem holds for Type III which is a region that happens to be both Type I and Type II.

I have two questions:

1. I am confused with what Type III are... If type I means left and right curves are vertical lines and type II means top and bottom curves are horizontal lines then doesn't that mean Type III region is a rectangle?
2. The final part of the proof is that the interior of the piceswise smooth simple closed curve can be decomposed into (finite?) number of Type III regions. Can someone provide a reference for this fact?

Thank you!

Comment: Type $III$ regions can also be a triangle, since they allow the length of one of the line segments to be 0

Comment: proof here does it the way described in the question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem

Comment: @Mason I believe 2 is true. A typical proof goes something like for Type I, one proves $\int_C P dx = - \int_D \partial P / \partial y dx dy$, the other half for Type II, then conclude that for Type III (simultaneously both) one has the desired Green's Theorem. see for example http://www.math.toronto.edu/courses/mat237y1/20189/notes/Chapter5/S5.2.html#sect-5.2.1

Comment: @JohnnyT. By 2, I mean the claim that any smoothly bounded region can be divided into finitely many regions of type I and can be divided into finitely many regions of type II. According to page 136 of https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/complex.pdf, "It is possible to concoct piecewise smoothly bounded domains that would require an
infinite number of divisions to yield subdomains of type I (or of type II).".

Comment: Also the Wikipedia proof shows that Green's theorem is true for regions that can be divided into finitely many regions of type I and can be divided into finitely many regions of type II. So this proof applies to many more regions than just type 3 regions. It seems that any region you can draw will probably be divisible in such ways, but math shows otherwise. As an alternative proof, Green's theorem for domains with $C^1$ boundary can be deduced from the Gauss-Green theorem.

Comment: @Mason first comment: It was misunderstanding, thank you for clarifying. 

second comment: I'm not quite seeing what you say... Wikipedia proof claims "Putting these two parts together, the theorem is thus proven for regions of type III (defined as regions which are both type I and type II). The general case can then be deduced from this special case by decomposing D into a set of type III regions." so it only seems regions that can be divided up into Type III pieces?

Comment: @JohnnyT. I'm saying that while the theorem is true for regions that can be divided into Type III pieces, the proof on Wikipedia actually lets you deduce more - namely that if the region can be divided into type I regions in some way, and type II regions in another way, then Green's theorem holds for the region. This is because when you divide into type I regions, you get equation (1) on Wikipedia, and when you divide into type II region, you get equation (2).

Comment: @Mason I see what you mean now. Thank you again for the clarification!